Access denied to upload file on sharepoint using Client ID and Secret Key
`Hello,
I am trying to upload file on the SharePoint using the PnPframework 1.13.0 in .net core 8 application. Few days ago, existing client id and secret id was expired and we have created new one using admin credentials and marked as trusted from below link. but somehow now when i am trying to upload file using existing code or powershell code with clientid and secret key then it gives me 403 FORBIDDEN error. so, could you please help us here what should we need to do? we have given full access to our users from where we have created keys.
URL:
https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx - To create keys https://xxx-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx - To grant permission.
Below is the code where we are trying to upload file
using (var sharePointContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, ClientID,SecretKey)){sharePointContext.Load(sharePointContext.Web, p => p.Title); sharePointContext.ExecuteQuery(); - Throws error from here }

